Is my weekly gym routine balanced enough?
I aim to go gym 4 times a week. My goal at the moment is to tone my stomach and to improve my general fitness overall. Recently I've become a bit concerned that my routine isn't balanced enough but need a second opinion.
All of my sessions start with a 5 minute jog and end with a 15 minute brisk walk on the treadmill set to a high incline.
Monday lower body

Lunges 12 reps x 10 kg x 3 sets
Barbell Squats 10 reps × 45 kg x 3 sets
Standing calf raises 15 reps x 3 sets
Leg press 10 reps x 80 kg x 3 sets
Seated leg curl 10 reps x 25 kg x 3 sets

Tuesday core

Lying leg raises 8 reps x 3 sets
Burpees 10 reps x 3 sets
Plank 30 seconds x 4 sets
Mountain climbers 12 reps x 3 sets

Thursday upper body

Dumbell row 6 reps (on each arm) x 10 kg x 4 sets
Lat pull down 10 reps x 30 kg x 4 sets
Push ups 6 reps x 3 sets

Friday lower body

Romanian deadlift 8 reps x 35 kg x 3 sets
Standing cable glute kickbacks 10 reps x 6.25 kg x 4 sets
Hip abduction machine 10 reps x 40 kg x 3 sets
Hip thrust 12 reps x 30 kg x 3 sets

What do you think?

What do you mean with 'toning' your stomach? https://physiqonomics.com/toning/

I am trying to lose fat, the only place I can visibly notice fat is on my stomach @Luciano

I'll go through this day by day:
Monday:
This seems good, but every time you do this routine you should aim to increase the weight and/or reps (progressive overload). Also, I suggest switching the order of lunges and barbell squats but it's based on preference. Maybe you should add a leg extension but you will probably be fine without.
Tuesday:
Obviously make sure to progressive overlord, but having a core focused day probably isn't a good idea. What you could do is do ab exercises at the end of your lower body days, and if you want more volume maybe your upper body days. Mountain Climbers and Planks are not great for abs, so what I recommend is doing an upper body workout, doing lower body again on Thursday and doing upper body again on Friday.
Thursday:
What you do good in this routine is you provide a decent amount of volume for back. Problem: Thats it. You do pushups, and then go home. I recommend doing 1 more chest exercise, adding some lateral raises, and some arm isolation exercises such as bicep curls and tricep extensions.
Friday:
This is good, but I suggest adding leg extensions here, as otherwise you wouldn't be hitting quads at all.
ALSO, TONING IS NOT A REAL CONCEPT. YOU CAN ADD MUSCLE AND YOU CAN LOSE FAT, BUT THATS IT. I recommend having a balanced training program, such as one found on the BoostCamp app, eating a balanced diet and recovering well. Make sure to train every muscle group twice a week to prevent imbalances.
